# Detect which button clicked from array

Tags: c#, events, button

I have a 2d array of buttons which each link to the same event handler:

```
    nb.Click += new EventHandler(this.nb_click);
    b[i][j] = nb;
    this.Controls.Add(b[i][j]);

    private void nb_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

I want it to be so that nb_click detects which button was pressed. Is there a way of going about this?

Solution: I had to set names for the button first, which in this case was nb.Name=...
Thanks, I just realized that.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#:" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Not tried this on C#, but is the sender param not the button that fired the event, (it is in most other GUI/event environments)?

Comment: Who remembers Control Arrays in VB6? good old days...

Answer (score 4):

That's what the `sender` argument is used for in your `EventHandler`. So simply associate an unique ID for this button so that you can recognize it back. Then cast the sender object argument to a button and look for the id. Then act accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

In the event handler, the `sender` parameter will be a reference to the button that was clicked.